# Error in my first table in kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm facing a problem when I try to insert a column in the database using Kotlin in Android.

This is the error:

> 08-04 19:45:03.781 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Zygote: v2
>   08-04 19:45:03.781 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   08-04 19:45:20.471 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:45:20.521 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:45:20.531 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:45:20.541 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
>   08-04 19:45:20.541 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@78b77
>   08-04 19:45:47.991 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:45:47.991 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:45:47.991 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:47:40.311 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
>   08-04 19:48:14.131 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Notes
>   08-04 19:48:14.141 14302-14302/com.example.hello.note E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Title=note Desc=desc
>                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Notes (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Notes(Title,Desc) VALUES (?,?)
>                                                                           #################################################################
>                                                                           Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                           Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                               (no such table: Notes (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Notes(Title,Desc) VALUES (?,?))
>                                                                           #################################################################
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1004)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:569)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1633)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1505)
>                                                                               at com.example.hello.note.DbManger.Insert(DbManger.kt:40)
>                                                                               at com.example.hello.note.addNotes.buAdd(addNotes.kt:24)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
>                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10931)
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Database code:

```
class DbManger(context: Context) {
    val dbName = "MyNotes"
    val dbTable = "Notes"
    val colID = "ID"
    val colTitle = "Title"
    val colDesc = "Desc"
    var dbVer = 4

    val sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTable + "(" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + colTitle + " TEXT," + colDesc + " TEXT " + ");"
    var sqlDataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    inner class dbHelperNotes : SQLiteOpenHelper {
        var context: Context? = null

        constructor(context: Context) : super(context, dbName, null, dbVer) {
            this.context = context

        }

        override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
            p0!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
            p0!!.execSQL("drop table IF EXISTS " + dbTable)
        }


    }

    fun Insert(values: ContentValues): Long {
        val ID = sqlDataBase!!.insert(dbTable, "", values)
        return ID
    }

    init {
        var db = dbHelperNotes(context)
        sqlDataBase = db.writableDatabase
    }
}
```

Comment: post database code here.

Comment: The error message is obvious. There is no such table. Did you create the tables before?

Comment: I updated the question, and I'm new in programming it's my first table :)

Comment: there are many obscure code in your question, :). you should point out where does the code is failed and with its stacktrace.

Comment: the code failed when I enter the title and desc in the app, and when I click add note button it added into the database and then the app failed.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Am I misusing tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@laalto is right, you need to re-create your table once you've dropped it, you need to add a call to `onCreate(p0)` inside your `onUpgrade()` method.

---

I removed a couple of unneeded fields on your class, this is how it looks now:

```
class DbManger(context: Context) {
    val dbName = "MyNotes"
    val dbTable = "Notes"
    val colID = "ID"
    val colTitle = "Title"
    val colDesc = "Desc"
    var dbVer = 4

    val sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $dbTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,$colTitle TEXT,$colDesc TEXT);"
    var sqlDataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    inner class dbHelperNotes(val context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbName, null, dbVer) {
        override fun onCreate(database: SQLiteDatabase?) {
            database?.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onUpgrade(database: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            database?.execSQL("drop table IF EXISTS " + dbTable)
            onCreate(database)
        }
    }

    fun insert(values: ContentValues): Long {
        val id = sqlDataBase!!.insert(dbTable, "", values)
        return id
    }

    init {
        val db = dbHelperNotes(context)
        sqlDataBase = db.writableDatabase
    }
}
```

I believe you also have a typo on your class name, should be 'DbManager'.

Answer (score 2):

Your database version is already at 4 but your `onUpgrade` merely drops the table but does not create the required tables.

If you want data-losing upgrades, you can just invoke `onCreate` in `onUpgrade` after dropping old tables. Or at development time, it's often just easier to uninstall and reinstall your app. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more about how `SQLiteOpenHelper` works.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall the app and it didnt work

Comment: Thanks for help :)